# Расположить все grid-элементы в ряд

Tags: html, css

Нужно расположить элементы в ряд. Как это можно реализовать через `grid` при условии, что кол-во элементов не известно. Или может есть другие решения?

В данном примере я использовал `repeat()`

```css
.slider {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 500px);
}

.slider .slide {
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
}

.slider .slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-auto-flow: column;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.slider {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src='https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/178/19/90/los_1000_d_850.jpg'></div>
</div>
```